# Node.js: Make sure a piece of code is executed after another

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

Given this code:

```
 c = new Customer 
 c.entry phone,req #how to make sure it ends before the next piece of code?

 db.Entry.findOne {x: req.body.x}, (err,entry) ->
```

How do I make sure that db.Entry.findOne is only executed after c.entry completes?

```
class Customer
  entry: (phone,req) ->
```

Comment: @muistooshort Entry is a method under class Customer. class Customer
 
 entry: (phone,req) ->

Comment: Can Entry be adjusted to take a callback?  You need some mechanism for knowing when Entry is done doing its thing, and callbacks are the primary mechanism.

Comment: So `entry` does something async and you wrote it? That async call should have a "complete" callback of some sort so tunnel your `findOne` call down to that callback.

Comment: @dyoo: Yup, callbacks calling callbacks calling callbacks, callbacks all the way down.

Answer (score 4):

Presumably your `entry` method does something asynchronous and that *something* should have a callback that runs when it finishes. So, just add a callback to `entry`:

```
class Customer
  entry: (phone, req, callback = ->) ->
    some_async_call phone, req, (arg, ...) -> callback(other_arg, ...)
```

I don't know what the arguments for `some_async_call`'s callback are or what you'd want to pass to `entry`'s callback so I'm using `arg, ...` and `other_arg, ...` as illustrative placeholders. If the arguments for `some_async_call` and the `entry` callback were the same then you could (as [Aaron Dufour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/593105/aaron-dufour) notes in the comments) just say:

```
entry: (phone, req, callback = ->) ->
  some_async_call phone, req, callback
```

And then move the `db.Entry.findOne` call into the callback thusly:

```
c = new Customer 
c.entry phone, req, -> 
  db.Entry.findOne {x: req.body.x}, (err, entry) ->
```

The details inside `entry` and the callback arguments would, of course, depend on what `entry` is doing and what `some_async_call` really is.

Any time you need to wait for something to happen in async (Java|Coffee)Script, you almost always solve the problem by adding a callback.

Comment: Any particular reason you pass `-> callback()` as the callback to `some_async_call` rather than just `callback`?  I believe they're functionally equivalent.

Comment: @AaronDufour: In the specific case where the `some_async_call` callback and `callback` get the same arguments (or they match as far as `callback` is concerned) then they would be the same. But I don't know what `some_async_call` does, what its callback gets, etc. so I thought it might be clearer to spell it out. Good question though.